# Traversing through a html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with this structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "#">link1</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link2</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link3</a></td>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" onclick = "func()"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

function func(){
  //I have to alert link1 here. 
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:** There are multiple rows of the same type and clicking on a particular check-box should alert the corresponding `<a>` text.

Comment: `alert($('td a:first').html())`

Comment: will there be multiple rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this with `jquery`. Just change the number of the `eq`. And all table with `input` with `class` of `checkbox` it will run. you can play with it.

```js
$('.checkbox').on('click',function(){
  var e = $(this).closest('table').find('td a');
  alert(e.eq(0).text());
});
```

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "#">link1</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link2</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link3</a></td>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <td><a href = "#">link4</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link5</a></td>
    <td><a href = "#">link6</a></td>
    <td><input type = "checkbox" class="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('td a');` won't this match with any other table if existing in the page?

Comment: nope, i will effect in all table, just use class on your table, so you can give specific function for that table.

Comment: @Anusha use class or ID on table to avoid effect on other tabel's

Comment: @mmativ Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, use a jQuery handler in which you can find the `a` value in the same row

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#my-table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first-child a').text())
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="my-table">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link-1-1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link-1-2</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link-1-3</a></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#">link-2-1</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link-2-2</a></td>
    <td><a href="#">link-2-3</a></td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```